# How do soda bottler costs break down?

Tags: microeconomics

I am curious what the typical breakdown of costs is for a soda bottler in the United States. I realize there are variations depending on region and brand. I am looking for ballpark estimates based on real knowledge (not guesses). The basic material costs I am looking for are:

- plastic bottle stubs
- labeling
- caps
- flavorant
- sweetener (corn syrup)
- all other costs (energy, wages, rents, taxes, etc)

Comment: You want a detailed industry analysis from an expert for free? That’s not how much that sort of analysis costs in the market. The only way you can get that sort of information easily is to find a publicly traded bottler, and look at its financial statements. However, almost all the categories mentioned would probably be lumped under 1-2 line items.